# Undefined variable in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am going to send email using gmail smtp in lumen, Everything working fine but one variable is always undefined, Please let me know where i am wrong

Here is my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MailService
{

    public static function send($mail_to = '', $title = '', $content = '') {
        Mail::send('mail', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message) {
            $message->from('noreply@gmail.com', 'Test Mail');
            $message->to($mail_to);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the Controller

```
public function register(Request $request)
{

    $rules = [
        'name'          => 'required',
        'email'         => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'      => 'required|min:5',
        'phone'         => 'required|numeric|min:10',
        'business_name' => 'required|unique:users',
        'business_type' => 'required'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    $data = $request->all();
    $hashPassword = Hash::make($data['password']);

    $data['password'] = $hashPassword;
    $data['is_activated'] = 'false';

    $pin    = mt_rand(1000, 9999); 
    $token  = hash("sha256", $pin);

    $data['token']  = $token;
    $data['otp']    = $pin;

    $user = User::create($data);

    if ($user) {
        MailService::send($request->input('email'), 'OTP', $pin);
        return response()->json(['response' => true, 'message' => 'User registered Successfully', 'token' => $token], 201);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['response' => false, 'message' => ' Please check your credentials, Try again'], 400);
    }
}
```

Here is the error

> {message: "Undefined variable: mail_to", exception: "ErrorException", file: "D:\xampp\htdocs\api\app\Services\MailService.php", line: 12, trace: Array(28)}
>
> exception: "ErrorException"
>
> file: "D:\xampp\htdocs\api\app\Services\MailService.php"
> line: 12
> message: "Undefined variable: mail_to"

Comment: which variable?

Comment: @Rp9 see update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `$mail_to`. you need to use it in function then you may use it otherwise you would get an undefined variable error as you're getting it now.

```
use($mail_to)
```

Here your code looks like below.

```
public static function send($mail_to = '', $title = '', $content = '') {
    Mail::send('mail', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message) use($mail_to) {
        $message->from('noreply@gmail.com', 'Test Mail');
        $message->to($mail_to);
    });
}
```

Comment: No, you didn't. In `Mail::send` method after function you need to use it. `function ($message) use($mail_to)` see this line in my answer. otherwise, copy this function and replace with your function your error will be gone.